# Passing additional context into CBV

Tags: django, django-views

I'm having trouble passing some additional context into a CBV. When I pass 'userprofile' as context, it prevents any other context from successfully being passed into the view.

**My view started as this:**

```
class OrderDetail(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Order

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try: 
            user_checkout = UserCheckout.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        except:
            user_checkout = None

        if user_checkout:
            obj = self.get_object()
            if obj.user == user_checkout and user_checkout is not None:  #checks to see if the user on the order instance ties to the user of the current request
                return super(OrderDetail, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                raise Http404

        else:
            raise Http404
```

**I then tried adding this**

```
     def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
         context = super(OrderDetail, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)            
         userprofile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
         context["userprofile"] = userprofile
```

I don't get any errors. It's just that when the page loads, none of the values that should appear (based on context) show up.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to add `return context` in your `get_context_data` method:

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
     context = super(OrderDetail, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)            
     userprofile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
     context["userprofile"] = userprofile
     return context
```

Also, as your **userprofile** has a relation(FK or OneToOne) with **User** model, you can simply access them template(without passing it in context) like this:

```
// If OneToOne
{{ user.userprofile }}

// If FK

{{ user.userprofile_set.first }}  // using reverse relationship to fetch userprofiles
```

For more details, please check documentations on [OneToOne](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/), [FK](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/), [Reverse Relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/relations/).